# Access parent form component

Tags: c#, forms, components

I'm beginner in C#, and I'm trying to change the property of a parent form component.
I have a button on the parent form that calls the child form, on the child form I've got another button, that should change the parent form button into invisible, when clicking it.
What should I do? I'll be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Have the child form hold a reference to the parent form.  This can be done in a private class variable, for example:

```
private ParentForm Parent { get; set; }
```

If the child form always needs this reference, require it in the constructor:

```
public ChildForm(ParentForm parent)
{
    if (parent == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("parent");
    Parent = parent;
}
```

So now when the parent form creates an instance of the child form, it supplies a reference to itself:

```
var childForm = new ChildForm(this);
```

Then anywhere in the child form you can access that instance of the parent form.  For example, the parent form can expose a method to hide the button:

```
public void HideButton()
{
    SomeButton.Visible = false;
}
```

Then the child form can invoke that method:

```
Parent.HideButton();
```